# Have lsof take action if a process has a file open — and, ideally, do so repeatedly

Tags: linux, bash, lsof

Per the EXAMPLES section in [the lsof(8) man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/en/man8/lsof.8.html#examples)
on manpages.ubuntu.com,
I should be able to run a command/take action if a process has a file open:

> To take action only if a process has `/u/abe/foo` open, use:
>
> ```
> lsof /u/abe/foo  echo "still in use"
> ```

When I try this syntax (in repeat mode), it doesn't work:

```
$ lsof -r /u/abe/foo tput bel
lsof: status error on tput: No such file or directory
lsof: status error on bel: No such file or directory
=======
```

I reviewed the man page,
but it's lengthy and I guess I've overlooked something.

What am I missing?

Comment: The TL;DR from [Eduardo Trápani’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769242/80216) is that this is an error in that copy of the man page. I guess that it was meant to say `lsof /u/abe/foo && echo "still in use"`, and a pre-processing step choked on the `&` characters.  Note that man page EXAMPLES are meant to be just that: ***examples*** /illustrations of what the main body of the page says. I see nothing in the page that talks about putting *another command* on the `lsof` command line. There are references to `lsof`’s exit status (I concede that they are obscure and cryptic). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … BTW, I find that [The Linux *man-pages* project](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) at man7.org (© 2024 [Michael Kerrisk](https://man7.org/mtk/index.html)) generally has the best man pages.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I concur! Feel free to add your comment as an answer as your solution works as well! Or I can!

Comment: The only part of my comment that works as a solution is already present in Eduardo Trápani’s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the manpage lists it, that is not a valid `lsof` invocation. `lsof` will consider `echo` and `still in use` as names:

```
lsof /u/abe/foo echo "still in use"
```

To have a result from `lsof` and act on it you could use the exit code. In `bash`:

```
lsof filename && echo "still in use"
```

or:

```
lsof filename || echo "not in use"
```

If you want this to happen repeatedly you can put the above code in a loop or put `lsof` in repeat mode and then process its standard output, for example in `bash`:

```
lsof -t -r2 filename |
grep --line-buffered -v '=======' |
while read pid
do
    echo Process $pid is using the file
done
```